# Migrating SSRS 2008 to 2016 - ReportSync cannot see Data Sources

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2016

I am trying to migrate our SSRS 2008R2 server to a fresh install of SSRS 2016.

I am using ReportSync and have managed to get connect to both servers OK. I created a test folder with a test report on the 2008 server and have migrated that fine to the 2016 server.

The problem is arising when I am trying to migrate the Data Sources folder.

As you can see from the screen shot, there is not plus symbol next to this folder, suggesting it is empty, yet when I browse the folder using the Reports Manager in Internet Explorer, I can see the Data Sources there. Furthermore, we have a Data Source in the Datasets folder (don't ask!) and when I expand that folder out in ReportSync, I cannot see this Data Source.

The credentials I have used in the ReportSync tool are the same as I am browsing the webpage with and this is a domain account. The account is in the BUILTIN\Administrators group which has "Content Manager" role on the Data Sources folder

[image]

Comment: Are you following the step 4 to export and map DataSources? https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SSRS-How-to-Import-Export-28660d6e

Comment: I hadn't but now I have tried that, I get an unhandled exception (which I can continue through) but then the dropdown lists in the resulting window are blank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to McNets for the heads up on the map DataSources option. To solve the problem I had to:

- Load up both servers as per the image in the question
- Select Tools > Map DataSources
- I was getting a runtime error at this point this was stopped by creating a datasource on the target server and clicking the "Load" buttons again in ReportSync
- The resulting window shows all the source server datasources with a dropdown list next to each allowing selection of the target server data sources
- Recreated all source server data sources on target server (including all the details - connection strings, authentication etc...
- Using the map datasources option, assign each source server data source to the relevant target server data source
- Click set
- Click sync at the bottom of the main window

The test report I created now opens